# Spearman correlation coefficient in MySQL - how to calculate average rating?

Tags: mysql, sql, correlation, rank

How can I calculate the average ranking of equal values?

I am trying to write a MySQL query that calculates the Spearman correlation coefficient. My idea is to write a query that calculates the Pearson correlation coefficient and using RANK () OVER (ORDER BY X) to rank the values before calculation.

I have managed to get this to work, see code below. But my problem is that all values that are the same value before ranking become the same value after ranking. My research tells me that equal values should get the average ranking of all equal values. How can this be incorporated in my query?

My code:

```sql
#setting values
SELECT
    @ax := avg(ranked_x) AS avg_x, 
    @ay := avg(ranked_y) AS avg_y,
    @div := (stddev_samp(ranked_x) * stddev_samp(ranked_y)) AS stddev
FROM
  (SELECT
      RANK() OVER(ORDER BY x) as ranked_x,
      RANK() OVER(ORDER BY y) as ranked_y
   FROM table) AS D;

#calculating the correlation coefficient with the values from the last query
SELECT
    sum( ( ranked_x - @ax ) * (ranked_y - @ay) ) / ((count(*) -1) * @div) AS correlation
FROM
   (SELECT
      RANK() OVER(ORDER BY x) as ranked_x,
      RANK() OVER(ORDER BY y) as ranked_y
   FROM table) AS D;
```

Example:

A data set with distinct values, such as [2, 16, 27, 28, 42], will be ranked [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. A data set with multiple identical values, such as [2, 2, 6, 6, 6], will be ranked [1.5, 1.5, 4, 4, 4].

This is because the two 2's are ranked number 1 and 2, and the average between 1 and 2 is 1.5. The three 4's are ranked numbers 3,4 and 5, and the average of these three values is 4.

Comment: Your variables gets the values which are calculated for the records which was processed the last, all previous values are rewrited (by the next ones), and so they are lost. Use CTE instead of variables.

Comment: I know CTE is an alternative to variables. But this will not solve my problem, Akina. Do you know how I can calculate the average ranking values of identical values in SQL?

Comment: @malhel . . . You should provide sample data and desired results, and a clear explanation of the formula you want to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description provided on [Wiki : Spearman's rank correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient#Example):

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS ( SELECT x,
                 y,
                 CAST(RANK() OVER(ORDER BY x) AS SIGNED) as ranked_x,
                 CAST(RANK() OVER(ORDER BY y) AS SIGNED) as ranked_y
          FROM src_table ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT x,
                 y,
                 ranked_x,
                 ranked_y,
                 ranked_x - ranked_y AS di,
                 (ranked_x - ranked_y) * (ranked_x - ranked_y) as di2
          FROM cte1 )
SELECT 1 - 6 * SUM(di2) / COUNT(*) / (COUNT(*) * COUNT(*) - 1) AS srcc
FROM cte2;
```

The same after compacting:

```sql
WITH 
cte AS ( SELECT POW((CAST(RANK() OVER(ORDER BY x) AS SIGNED) - CAST(RANK() OVER(ORDER BY y) AS SIGNED)), 2) as di2
         FROM src_table )
SELECT 1 - 6 * SUM(di2) / COUNT(*) / (COUNT(*) * COUNT(*) - 1) AS srcc
FROM cte;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bb431cf07264034a5520bdea6c56857e)

Comment: Thank you for this, Akina. However, to my understanding, this will not calculate the average value for identical values. From Wiki: "If ties are present in the data set, the simplified formula above yields incorrect results".

Comment: @malhel Imagine that you calculate ROW_NUMBER() for your data and calculate the rank `OVER (ORDER BY z, row_number)` - maybe it will give the result which you need? in such ordering all source rows become unique...

Comment: @malhel May you edit my fiddle and provide the source data with identical values accompanied with the desired result?

Comment: @malhel ... if your data do NOT contain full duplicates (either `x` or `y` or both differs in any rows pair) then `OVER (ORDER BY x,y)` and `OVER (ORDER BY y,x)` will be enough.

Comment: These were two great suggestions, but they sadly did not work. The reason is that the ranked value is still not calculated with average ranking. For example, a data set with distinct values, such as [2, 16, 27, 28, 42], will be ranked [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. A data set with multiple identical values, such as [2,2,6,6,6], will be ranked [1.5,1.5,4,4,4]. This is because the two 2's are ranked number 1 and 2, and the average between 1 and 2 is 1.5. The three 4's are ranked numbers 3,4 and 5, and the average of these three values is 4. Hope this gave a bit more clarification as to what I want to achieve.

Comment: @malhel *A data set with multiple identical values, such as [2,2,6,6,6], will be ranked [1.5,1.5,4,4,4].* This is wrong? but if so - what is correct? if correct ranking is [1,1,2,2,2] then you need DENSE_RANK() instead of RANK().

Comment: No, correct ranking is [1.5,1.5,4,4,4], not [1,1,2,2,2]. Sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: @malhel Please edit my fiddle, add YOUR source data, and give the link. And give desired result for this data. The solution posted in the comment above MUST solve.

Comment: I have edited your fiddle now, can you see it? The ranked_x is with your code is [1, 6, 7, 7, 2, 3, 3, 7, 7, 3], but the correct output should be [1, 6, 8.5, 8.5, 2, 4, 4, 8.5, 8.5, 4].

Comment: @malhel *I have edited your fiddle now, can you see it?* But where is the link to the edited fiddle? edit, then run, then copy new link...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this would help BTW what fiddle?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;
CREATE TABLE T
(VAL INT);
INSERT INTO  T VALUES
(2),(2),(6),(6),(6);

select t.val,aver
from t
join
(
select val, avg(rn) aver
from
(
SELECT VAL,
         row_number() over (order by val) rn
FROM T
) s
group by val
) s
on s.val = t.val
;

+------+--------+
| val  | aver   |
+------+--------+
|    2 | 1.5000 |
|    2 | 1.5000 |
|    6 | 4.0000 |
|    6 | 4.0000 |
|    6 | 4.0000 |
+------+--------+
5 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```